# when trying to execute mvn clean install -DskipTests=true its give an error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have import a spring boot project and once I execute 
 mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
its give me an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project collections-commons-util: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.fearson.collections.commons:collections-commons-util:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :collections-commons-util
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add a code-snipped to describe how you added the `json-lib` dependency? It should be something like that:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Failure to find net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository`

This is because previous attempt to download the artifact `net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4` failed so it will throw this error, you can force maven to try to download by using `-U` switch.

Try

```sh
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -U
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change you goal to `mvn clean install -U -Dskip.test=true` to force update the dependencies.